# MailApp don't send email if cell is blank

Tags: google-apps-script

I only know enough about coding to get myself in trouble. I have a code that allows me to send emails with my response to a user's response to my Google Form. However, I can't get it not send out an email if row 14 is blank. It sends out a blank email instead. I'd also like to know if it's possible to have the email automatically sent as soon as row 14 has a value, and if so, is it also possible to send a second email if row 14 is edited?

```
// This constant is written in column O for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:P
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2000)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];  // Second column
    var message = row[14];       // Third column
    var emailSent = row[15];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[3];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 16).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `continue` to cause the loop to go to the next row without sending an email:  `var message = row[14]; if (!message) {continue;}`

Comment: perfect, thank you!